# One Interface, Many Implementations

Tags: go

How do I translate the following Java code to Go?

```
interface NamePrinter {
    void print();
}

class NamePrinterWithoutGreeting implements NamePrinter {
    private string name;

    public NamePrinterWithoutGreeting(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
}

class NamePrinterWithGreeting implements NamePrinter {
    private string name;

    public NamePrinterWithoutGreeting(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + this.name);
    }
}
```

Type `NamePrinter` can reference an instance of both `NamePrinterWithoutGreeting` and `NamePrinterWithGreeting`:

```
void main(String[] args) {
    a NamePrinter = new NamePrinterWithoutGreeting("Joe");
    b NamePrinter = new NamePrinterWithGreeting("Joe");

    a.print(); // prints "Joe"
    b.print(); // prints "Hello, Joe"
}
```

Back to `go`... I'd like to have an `interface` of type `NamePrinter` that could reference many different implementations... but I don't know how to do it. Here below is an implementation... but it is fine for just one case:

```
type Person struct {
    name string
}

type NamePrinter interface {
    Create(name string)
    Print()
}

func Create(name string) *Person {
    n := Person{name}
    return &n
}

func (p *Person) print() {
    fmt.Println(p.name)
}

func main() {
    p := Create("joe")
    fmt.Println(p.Print())
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: My two cents https://tour.golang.org/methods/9

Comment: `print()` is not the same as `Print()`. Also you aren't actually using the interface type anywhere in your example Go code. There's no reason (with the `Print` method correctly named) this wouldn't work for as many types as you need it to. What is the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any type that you define, and on which you implement a set of methods that are equal in their signatures to those defined by an interface, that type can be used in place where you expect that interface.

```
type NamePrinter interface {
    print()
}

type NamePrinterWithoutGreeting struct {
    name string
}

func (p *NamePrinterWithoutGreeting) print() {
    fmt.Println(p.name)
}

type NamePrinterWithGreeting struct {
    name string
}

func (p *NamePrinterWithGreeting) print() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, ", p.name)
}

type MyInt int

func (i MyInt) print() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %d\n", i)
}

type MyFunc func() string

func (f MyFunc) print() {
    fmt.Println("Hello,", f())
}
func main() {
    var a NamePrinter = &NamePrinterWithoutGreeting{"joe"}
    var b NamePrinter = &NamePrinterWithGreeting{"joe"}
    var i NamePrinter = MyInt(2345)
    var f NamePrinter = MyFunc(func() string { return "funk" })
    a.print()
    b.print()
    i.print()
    f.print()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hW1q8eMve3

Comment: as a side note, mixing pointer method / non pointer methods breaks the interface signature compatibility (must be all pointer or all non pointer).

Comment: @mh-cbon maybe I'm misunderstading but it seems like you're saying if you mix pointer-reciever and value-receiver methods on a struct it can't fulfill an interface, which isn't true. Only the methods that are specified in the interface matter, other methods can use any receiver type (mixing pointer/value receivers is fine). It's generally a bad practice to mix receivers, but that has nothing to do with interfaces.